# Get set of classes in DOM that match given regex

Tags: javascript, collections

I am dynamically generating elements:

```
<a class="gallery1" href="base64String"> 
    <img src="base64StringThumbnail">
</a>
```

where numerical value suffix to `gallery` changes, I can't predict the numerical value ahead of time, so the regex for the class would be `"gallery\\d+"`.
I'd like get just all the classes without duplicates that match that regex

So I could write something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for(const clazz in matchedClasses){
    $('.' + clazz).createGallery();
  }
});
```

For instance if I have elements with classes: `gallery1, gallery2, gallery1, gallery3, gallery2` in DOM, I would get:
`[gallery1, gallery2, gallery3]` in any order.
that's easy for me in C# and Java, but I don't know how to achieve that in JS.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396497/get-all-items-that-start-with-class-name

Comment: `$( "a[class^='gallery']" )` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target all the elements with `querySelectorAll()` and *attribute starts with selector*. Then loop through them to get the class from the elements with `.map()`. Finally remove the duplicates using [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Try the following way:

```js
var galleryList = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="gallery"]');
var res = [...new Set(Array.from(galleryList).map(g => g.getAttribute('class')))];
console.log(res);
```

```html
<a class="gallery1" href="base64String"> 
  <img src="base64StringThumbnail">
</a>
<a class="gallery2" href="base64String"> 
  <img src="base64StringThumbnail">
</a>
<a class="gallery3" href="base64String"> 
  <img src="base64StringThumbnail">
</a>
<a class="gallery1" href="base64String"> 
  <img src="base64StringThumbnail">
</a>
<a class="gallery2" href="base64String"> 
  <img src="base64StringThumbnail">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let consider you can the following code which is all the classes as you said into a variable.

```
let allClasses = ['gallery1', 'gallery2', 'gallery1', 'gallery3', 'gallery2'];
```

Now to get only `['gallery1', 'gallery2', 'gallery3']` now do like this

```js
let allClasses = ['gallery1', 'gallery2', 'gallery1', 'gallery3', 'gallery2'];

let resultClasses = Array.from(new Set(allClasses));

console.log(resultClasses); // ['gallery1', 'gallery2', 'gallery3']
```

**Because the Set data structure guarantee the uniqueness of its values**